# Error: "The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected"

Tags: java, android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to start developing mobile applications with Android Developer Studio. I downloaded Android Developer Studio with SDK and JAVA requirements. But when I try to start my project, I get an error:

```
Error: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
At least one daemon option is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\mustafac\.gradle\daemon,pid=9040,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1254,-Duser.country=TR,-Duser.language=tr,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=89bee64b-dc23-47f4-a5f6-20fae6341e82,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\mustafac\.gradle\daemon,pid=3128,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1254,-Duser.country=TR,-Duser.language=tr,-Duser.variant,http://www.netmahal.com/?bd=hp&oem=hprotect&uid=WDCXWD10EZEX-08RKKA0_WD-WMC1S139379893798&version=&pid=3662073653&cs=6d6fd47ad2184eae96bfc61874ec42f4]
```

I also checked sth from internet and I tried to change JDK Location from project structure. But it didn't work for me. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you installed gradle standalong for something else before? because you have two running gradle deamons.

Comment: Multi-line code should be formatted by putting four spaces in front of each line, rather than using the backtick (`\``) method.

Answer (score 4):

I have also encountered this problem, for my case, I am using Intellij 15.06,
what solved my problem is just go to the directory, JAVA_HOME > jre > lib, and rename the tool.jar to tool.jar.bak, and then try to start a project or import a project again, at last, do not forget to rename it back to tool.jar.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This totally fixed my problem. Do you have any idea why this works?

Comment: @LanceClark needs to use jdk version i think

Comment: Saved my life, do you know the root cause?